# preventing mobile detection using flash content

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-builder

there are websites that force the policy of showing different content to desktop and mobile users. other than using appropriate UA string, there are also .flv files on the web too! so somehow they detect the mobile device and don't show the desktop content.

analyzing this flash behaviors is important to one of our projects that is a mobile app, so for security reasons there has to be a stealth mode in the software to protect the mobile user from being identified as a mobile user when he access the certain websites in our partner company.

**how can you control this behavior from the client browser?**

any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Check out the headers sent by the client browsers. Usually user agent string is used to identify the browser (and is pretty simple to send a fake user agent string). There are extension for firefox mobile which allow you to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what they are doing.  Mobile device detection can be simply a matter of checking screen size or user agent, but it could be any number of other things as well.

To figure out exactly what you need to do, run the swf file through something like [swfscan](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Following-the-Wh1t3-Rabbit/SWFScan-FREE-Flash-decompiler/ba-p/5440167) or [ASDec](http://code.google.com/p/asdec/).

If they are using flash, I imagine they are doing more than just a basic user agent string.  They might be looking at device capabilities that cannot be easily adjusted.

It is strange to use flash for detection - since it won't work on iphones at all.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the checks (aside from the UA string) are done using either css media queries or javascript. These will be very hard for you to control unless you can create a customized browser (Possible on Android, lots harder / impossible on iOS).

The most obvious checks done to check if you are on a phone:

- User Agent String (as mentioned by yourself)
- Sceen size (using javascript)
- css media queries

Of course there are other reasons to not show flash to a visitor, using detection on:

- Supported media (video tag)
- Specific flash test using SWFObject or something like that (javascript based)

If you really don't want people to know you are on a phone use a remote desktop connection to a 'real' computer and use a browser on the remote system. RDP for windows, VNC for windows/osx/more, or a dedicated system like TeamViewer. There are apps available for most of these remote connection systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check browser's version in flash, you may use [this](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-detect-the-browser-and-user-agent-with-as3/) tip. If you want your mobile browser to recognized as a desktop's one, you have to change User Agent settings. Here is an [example](http://www.1800pocketpc.com/change-user-agent-on-opera-mobile-95/) how to do it in Opera Mobile.